# How find my board's IP within a network without monitor?

Tags: networking, ssh, ip, lan

I have a network in my workplace and also have a laptop(Ubuntu Desktop 16.04) connected to it by Wi-Fi with the IP address `10.13.0.82`. I also have a `nanopi-M1` board with Ubuntu-server installed on it. I connected my board via its LAN port. I tried to search the IP addresses with `Angry IP scanner` from `10.13.0.` to `10.13.0.255` but only can find my laptop. Is it possible to find my board?

I have a `Yealink` telephone in my office uses that network by this IP address too: `172.20.4.65`, but when I search this IP or try to connect it by `SSH` command by my laptop, it can not find it (I attached my board to external LAN port of my phone).

Comment: Is it not running Avahi?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I don't know what is it?

Comment: What OS do you have on your laptop? Windows?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Ubuntu desktop 16.04

Comment: Sounds like you are in an Enterprise grade network... Your laptop probably is connected to a client isolated WiFi, meaning that subnet is setup so you can't see other devices on it, and the Yealink phone is probably in a subnet (voice VLAN) that isn't routeable to 10.13.0.X IP address. Honestly, you should probably talk to your IT support staff or at least get a better understanding of your network environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not an engineering way but I could find my board in this way:

I searched the IP range of my `Yealink` phone from `172.20.0.0` to `172.20.4.255` and found all the results from `172.20.0.0` to `172.20.0.255`. There were 18 active clients. Then I wrote their number in a paper and connected and this connected my board and searched for few times and found my IP by this TRIAL and ERROR manner!

Comment: Based on the IP addresses you are using, it is obvious that the IP is IPv4, so why are you asking to find the IP if you already know it?

Comment: I didn't know it! I found this range from my phone's status menu!
If you like I can DELETE my answer!!

Comment: Just as a small FYI, if you want, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: You know that the IP is IPv4, so why are you asking what the IP is? There are only two IPs: IPv4 and IPv6. You were only using IPv4, so that is the IP.

Comment: @RonMaupin: I am not a network expert! I only wanted to connect my board via `SSH` and asked this question! I don't know even exactly what `IPv4` and `IPv6` are

Comment: @Anaksunaman: thanks, but it says you can do it after 2days

Comment: Yes, there's a delay. Should have made that clear. Good catch.

Comment: IP means Internet Protocol. There are two current Internet protocols: IP version 4 and IP version 6. All the addresses in your answer are IPv4 addresses, so you know the IP is IPv4. I am asking why you are looking for the IP if you know it is IPv4 by the IP addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin In conventional English, when one asks, "What is your IP?", they're asking for the IP *address*, not the version.

Comment: @RonMaupin: maybe it's because of my bad English or few knowledge in networks. I meant my board address in the network by `IP` word.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, no. English is my native language (really Texan). IP stands for Internet Protocol. If I ask for someone's IP, I want to know if he is using IPv4 or IPv6. If I want to know the IP address, I ask for the IP address. I could see asking for someone's IPA as the Internet Protocol Address, but IP has stood for Internet Protocol since it was created. Why does it mean IP address any more than it means IP mask, IP version, IP TTL, IP DSCP, etc.?

Comment: @RonMaupin Always doing it bigger in Texas, eh! :) I guess it's because when discussing configuration details related to TCP/IP, the vast majority of the time it's the address that's of interest.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the board has Ubuntu on it, that would means that so, the easy way is too check in the DHCP server for new leases as Ubuntu tends to enable DHCP client automatically.

Failing that run a port scan for open 22 ports in your network range until you find correct server which is effectively what you did. For that, NMAP is your friend as it can produce a limited list rather than just IP’s found in the network.